# MS.Win32.Penimc.UnsafeNativeMethods Visual Studio 2015 and Sql Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: windows, windows-update

I am getting the following error after patch KB3186497 was installed on my machine.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced a similar issue and the culprit was Microsoft .Net 4.7 Framework. I had to uninstall 4.7 and then installed 4.6 version. Now it works fine.

Comment: I think this is proper solution for this problem. WHen you just disable pen in VS then you won't be able to run installer (since you won't be able to modify it's settings file)

Answer (score 7):

[Microsoft Forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/mswin32penimcunsafenativemethods/e572fda8-49e6-4c5f-ae35-27c9381f3533)

This worked for me:

**Visual Studio 2015**

1. Find the devenv.exe.config file. It is located in the folder `<VS Install Location>\Common7\IDE`.
2. Copy devenv.exe.config to a non-protected folder, for example your Documents folder, and then create a backup copy of
   devenv.exe.config.
3. Open devenv.exe.config, and modify the `<AppContextSwitchOverrides>` element to add `Switch.System.Windows.Input.Stylus.DisableStylusAndTouchSupport=true`

**SSMS 2012**

1. Find the Ssms.exe.config file. It is located in the folder `<SSMS Install Location>\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\`.
2. Copy Ssms.exe.config to a non-protected folder, for example your Documents folder, and then create a backup copy of
   Ssms.exe.config.
3. Open Ssms.exe.config, and add the element `<AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Windows.Input.Stylus.DisableStylusAndTouchSupport=true" />` above the element `<assemblyBinding>`    in `<runtime>`

Comment: Huge Help! Fixed the issues we were having at work following .NET framework update KB3186497.

Comment: This was a lifesaver.. I updated to windows 10 and this issue started. Your solution fixed it.